# How to implement Flutter Cards with Previous and Next button

Tags: flutter

I have 4 different Cards with Radio button. I want to implement  Previous and next button at the end of every cards. At the end of the last Card I want a Submit button that will submit the whole form.

Can anyone tell me how can I implement this logic??

Comment: Could you provide your base code? your question seems very broad. Are you using a `pageview` at all to swipe between the cards? or are they getting pushed through the `navigator`? or is it a `tabview`?

Comment: The pages are getting pushed through Navigator now.. but that thing I don't want. Can you share me any other logic?

Comment: I'd suggest a `PageView`, remove the swiping gesture if unneeded and control the Page change programmatically with a `PageController`. you can then check in which page you're on through the controller's index and build the button based on that.

Comment: Thank you for your submission.